# Copy files over before jarring

Tags: gradle

I can't get my script to wait until libraries are copied over to 'src/main/resources/libs' before it starts to jar up everything. The files are copied over but the jar task I think is not waiting until the files are copied over? Because they are not added to my jar. Unless I run script again :/ How to fix this?

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.myLib
    into 'src/main/resources/libs'
}

jar.dependsOn 'copyDependencies'

jar {
   manifest {} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the execution order right, `processResources` would have to depend on `copyDependencies`. However, you shouldn't copy anything into `src/main/resources`. Instead, the libraries should be included directly in the Jar, without any intermediate steps:

```
jar {
    into("libs") {
        from configurations.myLib
    }
}
```

This assumes that there is some custom process or class loader in place that makes use of the libraries in the Jar's `libs` directory. A standard JVM/class loader will ignore them.

Comment: thanks.  I don't see why I can't get jar task to depend on something to run prior.

Comment: You can, and you did. But that wasn't the right dependency, as the `jar` task pulls from `build/classes/main`, but you copied into `src/main/resources`. So you'd have to come before the task that copies from `src/main/resources` into `build/classes/main`, which is `processResources`.